# Pgadmin 4 pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql

Tags: pg-dump, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

Hi I am using Postgres 11 and pgadmin 4.1. I have a SQL file i am trying to import in my newly created database in pgadmin 4.

I know its a generalized error but I tried my best to resolve it, but not working for me.

Here is the error:

[image]

Here are a few SQL file lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two things in a plain text dump that may prevent it being restored using the query tool og pgAdmin:

- backslash commands, like the `\connect` you get if you use the `--create` option of `pg_dump` (only `psql` understands these)
- `COPY` commands to load the data, because pgAdmin does not support mixing SQL and data the way that `psql` does

So if the dump was created without `--create` and with either `--schema-only` or `--inserts`, it will probably load fine.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem in my case, as automated pgadmin dump does contain backslash command; and strangely pgadmin dump as sql cannot be restored.

Comment: @Polv My answer was incomplete. I have improved it.